# Apply formatting for string in Azure to TextBlock

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services to store the data in my application. One of my fields is set as nvarchar (max) and within that field is going to be a long list of times.

Before, when my data was stored in the application itself, I would format the string as such:


 
**"Header Text \n• Item \n• Item \n• Item \n Header \n• Item"**


This would then skip to a new line on ever "\n" that was encountered. Now, when pulling the data from Azure and binding it to the **TextBlock**, it doesn't skip to a new line.

I've looked to see if there was a MultiLine property for the **TextBlock**, and there is not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to accomplish this via the application code. Instead, I built a simple application that loaded that data from the database. Once the data was loaded, I applied the necessary formatting and saved the data. It was then reflected in the client application.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `AcceptsReturn` property in the `<TextBox>` XAML control to true, it will display the text in multiple lines. This sample app below does just that:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="btnStart" Content="Click me"
                Click="btnStart_Click" />
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtDebug"
                 Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "https://YOUR-APP-NAME.azure-mobile.net/",
        "YOUR-APPLICATION-KEY"
    );

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var table = MobileService.GetTable<Test>();
            var item = new Test
            {
                name = "Header Text \n• Item \n• Item \n• Item \n Header \n• Item"
            };

            await table.InsertAsync(item);
            var inserted = await table.LookupAsync(item.id);
            this.txtDebug.Text = inserted.name;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.txtDebug.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**Update after the edit to the original post**. Using a `<TextBlock>` works just as well. As long as the text block is set up with a height of more than one line (in the example below, by binding it to a grid cell), it will display the multiple lines correctly, without the need for any additional property (like `AcceptsReturn` on text boxes). If you replace the control panel grid declaration in the XAML file above with the one below, you'll see that the multiple lines will be displayed on the text block.

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="btnStart" Content="Click me"
                Click="btnStart_Click" />
        <TextBlock Text="This will be replaced&#10;after the call to the Mobile Service" Grid.Row="1"
                   Margin="10" Name="txtDebug"/>
        <!--<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtDebug"
                 Grid.Row="1" />-->
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I meant TextBlock not TextBox.

Comment: I'm still not able to fix the issue. I've uploaded a sample project to my [SkyDrive](http://sdrv.ms/12fCDWs). The way I'm doing my binding, is a little different. Thanks again.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?